# NodeJS concurrent web server

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm creating NodeJS App which calls 5 external Web service APIs. 
then results are processed and output is generated on nodeJS/express web server.

it can not handle 200 concurrent users. it does serve output but after 30 seconds.

ETIMEDOUT and ESOCKETIMEDOUT errors are generated in web service calls.

i have set sysctl.conf to maximum and http.globalAgent.maxSockets=Infinity;utilizing all cores 
but still its not working.

Same server running PHP can serve 1000 concurrent connections.
Simple Webserver can't serve 200 concurrent connections.

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets=Infinity;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: Could you show your code ?

Comment: Original Code is of 700 lines.to test nodeJS i put simple web server and hit it with 200 apache bench concurrency but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe one or more of the 5 webservers you are calling is blocking because of too much requests. When you do 200 requests to your node.js server, and this in turn does each request another 5 outgoing requests, this in sum is 1000 requests to other webservices. I guess the external webservice is blocking or forcing you to wait (throttling).

Comment: @DanFromGermany our current system in PHP is doing the same Job.
our IPs are whitelisted in web services so its not the case.
even i tried with simple web server which isn't calling APIs wasn't able to handle 200 concurrent connection

Comment: Can you share your ab command ? I can hit that example with 1K concurrent requests without any issues: http://pastebin.com/WzwCBcFw

Comment: ab -n 10000 -c 250 -r http://192.252.214.155:1337/

Comment: Do you have ssh access ? Could your run ab from the server it self to see if this is network related ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer i tried ab from local machine it worked just fine.